# Create a folder in Livelink with VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access, outlook, livelink

I am looking for the easiest and fastest way to create a folder in Livelink with VBA. I'm working with Microsoft Access 2003. For example, I want to create a folder into `Livelink\Enterprise\folder1\folder2\`. I also have the `folder2 LivelinkID` (7 digits) stored in my Access database. The Livelink server takes about ~1-2 seconds to respond each times I ping it.

What would be the best method to create a folder into Livelink within my VBA project? Livelink version is 9.7.1.0.814 with Livelink Explorer (Connect) 4.8.2.397, using Outlook 2003.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it working with WebDAV. It would work too with MAPI but it's really long to reach a deep parent folder (going thru folder by folder each times).

Here is the function I got:

```vb
Public Function CreateFolderToLLFolder(parentId As String, folderName As String) As String
    Dim dav As New ADODB.Record
    Dim elements As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim fields(1) As Variant
    Dim values(1) As Variant

    dav.Open URL_WEBDAV & parentId, "", adModeReadWrite, , , LLUser, LLPassword
    Set elements = dav.GetChildren

    fields(0) = "RESOURCE_PARSENAME"
    values(0) = folderName 

    fields(1) = "RESOURCE_ISCOLLECTION"
    values(1) = True

    elements.addnew fields, values

    elements.Close
    Set elements = dav.GetChildren
    dav.Close

    elements.MoveFirst
    Do Until elements.EOF
        If elements("RESOURCE_DISPLAYNAME") = folderName Then
            Exit Do
        End If
        elements.MoveNext
    Loop
    If Not elements.EOF Then
        dav.Open elements
        CreateFolderToLLFolder = dav("urn:x-opentext-com:ll:properties:nodeid")
    Else
        CreateFolderToLLFolder = -1
    End If

    dav.Close
    elements.Close
Exit Function
```

URL_WEBDAV is for example `http://livelink.yourserver.com/livelinkdav/nodes/`. Also use `LLUser` and `LLPassword` if needed.